# ElementaryOS not recognized by Grub2

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot, elementary-os

(The hyperlinks are pictures I took)

I had Windows10 installed in my computer (which is a Lenovo Z70) and I installed ElementaryOS but [Grub2 is not recognizing the OS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvz2ocegjyzpvu1/IMG_20160118_143905.jpg?dl=0), actually none of them.
If I type `exit` then I get to the [Boot Manager](https://www.dropbox.com/s/koqqgu5bjfx26i0/IMG_20160118_143932.jpg?dl=0) and I can find Windows but not Linux.

For the installation I created a `swap area (2GB)` and an `Ext4 file system`.

Comment: first boot into Windows 10 and disable `Fast startup/hybird shutdown` and also disable secure boot from BIOS, the repair grub

Comment: @edwardtorvalds, fast startup and secure boot were already disabled. You say I need to repair grub now? Any good tutorial on how is it done?

Comment: follow this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu), install the `Boot Repair` follow the recommended repair way. this way your boot will be repaired and report back here. NOTE: I have same computer :D

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I dowloaded it and ran recommended repair after my 2nd installation and I got the results into pastebin (http://paste2.org/BdmVXexk). Yet I don't understand this results...

Comment: on which partition you have installed Elementary OS? I cant see any ext4 formatted partition all are ntfs... this means Elementary OS isnt installed. the report says `1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 0 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.`

Comment: @edwardtorvalds that's the thing! I created a swap space on sda8 and installed on sda9. I'll run repair again and I'll paste here the result again. Give me some minutes (thanks for the patience btw)

Comment: you should check whether the ISO of E OS is corrupt or not. you can do that from here https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download

Comment: @edwardtorvalds hello again. I did checked and everything seems fine with the ISO. Still don't know what's wrong with but I truly believe it's some problem with grub. I ran Boot repair but I noticed nothing wrong. Maybe I should unninstall grub2?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I downloaded eOS ISO again and it seems the previous one had 2/3 of this new one's size. Now it worked, it's installed and functional. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion we had in our chat I think you should check whether the ISO you downloaded is complete and not corrupt which you can do it from [here](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download)

In your case following things didn't work:

1. Disabling Secure boot in BIOS and Hybrid shut-down in Windows 10
2. Reinstalling Elementary OS
3. Repairing GRUB

The only thing you should do now is check whether your ISO for corruption, if it is corrupted then download the ISO again; which what worked for you